why does fun.__code__.co_names not include all global variables?
Here's some python code:
dict_de_en = {'we':'wir', 'love':'lieben', 'cake':'kuchen'}
def fun1(sentence): 
    return " ".join([dict_de_en[w] for w in sentence.split()])
def fun2(sentence): 
    dd = dict_de_en
    return " ".join([dd[w] for w in sentence.split()])
print("f1:", fun1("we love cake")) # "wir lieben kuchen"
print("f2:", fun2("we love cake")) # ditto
print("n1", fun1.__code__.co_names) # ('join', 'split')
print("n2", fun2.__code__.co_names) # ('dict_de_en', 'join', 'split')

why does fun1 not contain dict_de_en in .co_names?
It does work as expected for:
dict_de_en = {'we':'wir', 'love':'lieben', 'cake':'kuchen'}
def fun3(word): 
    return dict_de_en[word]
def fun4(word): 
    dd = dict_de_en
    return dd[word]
print("f3:", fun1("we")) # "wir"
print("f4:", fun2("we")) # ditto
print("n3", fun3.__code__.co_names) # ('dict_de_en',)
print("n4", fun4.__code__.co_names) # ('dict_de_en',)

The background is that I am running a Python MOOC with automated task scoring. It should find and warn informatively about the usage of global variables in the participant's solution functions. My setup generally works well so far, except for the situation in fun1.

From Python 3.0 to Python 3.11, list comprehensions are implemented by creating and calling an anonymous function. In fun1, that anonymous function is the one that uses dict_de_en.
fun1's own bytecode doesn't use that global variable, so it doesn't show up in the code object's co_names.
In Python 3.12, with the implementation of PEP 709, list comprehensions are inlined instead of using a separate function, so you'll see dict_de_en in fun1's bytecode on Python 3.12 and up.

Thank you so much for the quick and informative response!
So I guess there is no automated way in older versions to catch global vars in list comprehensions... (which is OK, by this point in the course they should know)

As you said.
From my perspective - fun1 simply does not use global variable, it uses .join() which uses the global variable... Therefore, fun1 will not display global variable which it does not use.

You are only looking in the scope of your outer function
As the answer by @user2357112, code_object.co_names does not return names in nested functions, including list comprehensions. Even though list comprehensions will be inlined in Python 3.12, the general issue still applies in later Python versions, e.g.:
def fun3(sentence):     
    return lambda sentence: dict_de_en
fun3.__code__.co_names # ()

You could define a recursive function to look in the code names of any functions used within the function, including list comprehensions:
def get_co_names(code_obj):
    co_names = set(code_obj.co_names)
    for const in code_obj.co_consts:
        if isinstance(const, type(code_obj)):
            co_names.update(get_co_names(const))
    return co_names

print("n1", get_co_names(fun1.__code__)) # n1 {'dict_de_en', 'join', 'split'}
print("n2", get_co_names(fun2.__code__)) # n2 {'dict_de_en', 'join', 'split'}
print("n3", get_co_names(fun3.__code__)) # n3 {'dict_de_en'}

Using single dispatch
This may be needlessly fancy but I don't like having to pass fun1.__code__ rather than just fun1. We can't just make the recursive function take a function argument as co_consts returns an object of types.CodeType rather than types.FunctionType. But we can use functools.singledispatch to create a generic and then apply the relevant function depending on the type of the argument passed to it:
from functools import singledispatch
import types

@singledispatch
def get_co_names(obj):
    raise TypeError(f"Unsupported type: {type(obj)}")

@get_co_names.register
def _(code_obj: types.CodeType):
    co_names = set(code_obj.co_names)
    for const in code_obj.co_consts:
        if isinstance(const, types.CodeType):
            co_names.update(get_co_names(const))
    return co_names

@get_co_names.register
def _(func_obj: types.FunctionType):
    return get_co_names(func_obj.__code__)

This allows us to pass the function itself as the argument rather than e.g. fun1.__code__:
print("n1", get_co_names(fun1)) # n1 {'dict_de_en', 'join', 'split'}
print("n2", get_co_names(fun2)) # n2 {'dict_de_en', 'join', 'split'}
print("n3", get_co_names(fun3)) # n3 {'dict_de_en'}


Well thank you so much! get_co_names(fun.__code__) does a wonderful job for me :)
